# Реггулярное выражение не отрабатывает

Tags: java

Прошу помощи .. Есть метод принимает в себя ввод с клавиатуры. Есть 2-ве регулярки, которые должны определить, корректен ли ввод и с помощью if внести значения в переменные.
При вводе с клавиатуры 11 значного номера имеем false, несмотря на то, что номер корректен.

```
public void inputCheck(String input) {
        String regexPhone = "[0-9]{11}+";
        String regexName = "[а-яёА-ЯЁ] + [^0-9,@\\? \\!]";
        String name = "";
        String phone = "";
        if (regexName.matches(input)) {
            name = input;
            System.out.println(Main.setNmbrMsg);
           }
        else if (regexPhone.matches(input)) {
            phone = input;
            System.out.println(Main.setNamMsg);
        } else {
            System.out.println(Main.errorMsg);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Неправильно вызываются методы [`String::matches`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)), они должны вызываться для переменной `input`:

```java
if (input.matches(regexName)) {
    name = input;
    System.out.println("Имя: " + name);
} else if (input.matches(regexPhone)) {
    phone = input;
    System.out.println("Телефон: " + phone);
} else {
    System.out.println("Main.errorMsg = " + input);
}
```

2. Регулярки для определения имени / телефона содержат ошибки:

- `"[0-9]{11}+"` - позволяет номера телефонов длиной 22, 33 и т.д. цифр, следует убрать плюс
- `"[а-яёА-ЯЁ] + [^0-9,@\\? \\!]"` - проверяет формат имени в виде одной русской буквы, после которой идут 2 или более пробелов и один произвольный символ, не являющийся цифрой, пробелом, запятой, собакой, или знаками `?!`

Comment: Спасибо разобрался ... тут немного сложнее. `public void inputCheck(String input) {
        String regexPhone = "([0-9]{11})";
        String regexName = "([А-ЯЁа-яё]{1,}[^0-9\\@\\?\\!])";
        
        if (input.matches(regexName)) {
            name = input;
            System.out.println(Main.setNmbrMsg);
           }
        else if (input.matches(regexPhone)) {
            phone = input;
            System.out.println(Main.setNamMsg);
        } else {
            System.out.println(Main.errorMsg);
        }
    }`